# "...and the fire from the stove engulfed him" or "jumped on him" or "covered him" or "devoured him" or what?

Tags: style

Which verb should I use here?

> He opened the stove and the fire from the stove [engulfed/jumped on/covered/devoured] him. "Help! Help!" - he shouted at once. "I'm on fire!"

Comment: Might be better for writers.se?

Comment: I agree with @JSBangs. The writers crew would probably be more suited for this question.

Comment: OP doesn't actually say he's looking for a wonderfully evocative term for use in his hopefully deathless prose, which would make it a candidate for writers.se. He may just want to know what word (cliche?) most people would use in common speech, which I think properly belongs at english.se

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "*He may just want to know what word (cliche?) most people would use in common speech*" - You are right. I was quite surprised when I discovered that my question had been moved to writers.se. As a person who is merely studying English, I, of course, wasn't trying to write any prose.

Comment: @brilliant: Well thank you for that acknowledgement. I'm afraid I'm pretty much of a noob to **english.se** myself so I don't know whether or how one can avoid such slip-ups. You'll be ok because you'll know to explain more exactly what kind of answer you want, and why. But other students of English will probably get wrongly moved in future. Incidentally, am I right in suspecting you asked what you did because there's a 'standard' expression in Taiwanese?

Comment: Repetition of the word "stove" is not required and sounds awkward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How big is this stove?

I'm not asking idly. "Engulfed" means (as noted by others) "completely surrounded." If a fire engulfs someone, he is surrounded, head to foot, in flames. How can he be yelling that he's on fire if he's burning everywhere? And how can he be swallowed by fire if it's just a cooking fire from something burning in an oven? (I assume "oven," as you don't open a stove. A stove is a rangetop of freestanding burners.)

Maybe your problem is that it's not that *he* is on fire. It's one or a few body parts which are burning.

so howzabout this:

> He opened the oven to check on the [food/dish]. Flames roared out, catching him full in the face. He shrieked and batted at his burning hair and skin with the oven mitts. Hot grease ran down the gloves to his thin sleeves, where it started to smoke. "Help! I'm on fire!" he shouted.

Comment: @Lauren - Yes, you are right. It's just an oven, so now your variant looks to me more suitable. "*catching him full in the face*" - Is "*to catch <smbd.> full in face*" a phrasal verb in English? Can *full* be dropped here?

Comment: @brilliant: You can say "in the face" and drop "full" if you want. "Full in the face" is an idiom which emphasizes that it went straight into his face and has covered his entire face. "He caught X in the face" means that X struck him in the face and he was surprised by X. A variant might be "He caught the blow [meaning the punch] in the stomach" meaning "The other guy punched him in the stomach, he was surprised by the punch, and he didn't defend himself." Does that help?

Comment: Yes, and ["Help! I'm on fire!" he shouted] is much stronger than ["Help! Help!" - he shouted at once. "I'm on fire!"].

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum - (1) Lauren, in fact, I am a bit confused now by your comment. You said "*"He caught X in the face" means that X struck him in the face and he was surprised by X*", from which it can be clearly seen that it is *X* who is the "agent", i.e. the one who is striking, while *he* is the "patient", i.e. the one who receives the blow. So, your words could be

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum - (2) presented in this formula: "He caught X in the face" = "He received a blow from X". But in your answer given earlier you said "*Flames roared out, catching him full in the face*", which, if I follow the same logic, would mean that the fire (flames) received a blow from him(!) I am kind of confused now. Can you, please, explain it to me?

Comment: @Panda - WOW!!! Thank you, I didn't think of that.

Comment: Sorry, English idioms can be a little confusing, and my fire example is inverted. The "catching" comes from the movement of the item (flames, fist) towards the person who is surprised. Let me reword: "He caught the punch in the stomach = he was struck by the fist in the stomach" and "He caught the flames in the face = he was struck by the flames in the face." Flames don't strike, but the movement is out of the oven at and his face; the other example is that the fist moves towards the person and strikes him in his stomach. The flames do not receive a blow from X. The flames ARE X. Clearer?

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum - Yes, now it's clear. Thank you. Three small follow-up questions: Your rewording goes "*He caught the flames in the face*" - 1) Can the word "*full*" be inserted in here, just like it was in your original example? 2) Can I replace "*the face*" with "*his face*"? 3) And finally, how can this whole phrase be inserted into your original example properly (could it go like this: "*...check on the dish. Flames roared out and he caught the flames (full/right) in the/his face. He shrieked and batted at his...*")? Sorry for asking too many questions. I just really like your example.

Comment: @brilliant: ask away. :) 1) Yes, you can add "full" or "right." 2) No, the idiom uses "the," not "his." It's understood that he couldn't catch the flames in somebody else's face, so the face has to be his. 3) I am reluctant to accept your revision because the flames, not being a sentient actor, need to be attached to the action (burning his face). If this were a fistfight, you could say "He opened the door and Nancy rushed out. She swung her fist, and he caught the punch full in the stomach." (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) In your example, the flames aren't choosing to burn him; it's just an accident. So I really feel like you have to put the movement of the flames roaring out of the oven in the same sentence as what the flames did (burn him). In a fistfight, there are a series of movements: fist raised, drawn back, punch. It takes a second. In your example, he opens the oven and the flames hit him instantly. Almost no time elapses. My sentence structure captures the sequence more accurately, I think: "Flames roared out, catching him full/right in the face."

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum - So your original example is still correct! I am sorry, I misunderstood you - I thought that when you said "*my fire example is inverted*" you were saying that it was wrong (I am not a native English speaker, so I misunderstand things in English quite often). Well, in this case everything is fine - I'll just take it the way you originally presented it in your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I would say either *engulfed him*, if you want to imply that he was completely surrounded with flames, or *jumped on him* or *jumped toward him*.

But, most importantly, I would talk about “***the flames***” rather than “***the fire***”.

Comment: @F'x - *But, most importantly, I would talk about “the flames” rather than “the fire”.* - Can you, please, explain why not "the fire"?

Comment: I'm not sure, it just feels better. I think the flames personify the fire, so that the flames jump or engulf, rather than the fire itself. It seems to build a better image in my mind…

Comment: "Fire" is a collective noun; "flames" are individual things (as much as a single flame in the middle of a conflagration can be "individual"). "The fire engulfed him" is an image of a blob of fire swamping  him like water -- it's amorphous. "The flames engulfed him" is a series of tentacles seizing him and crawling up his limbs, this one and that one and that one and another AND ANOTHER until  he's surrounded. Much scarier.

Comment: @F'x - *I think the flames personify the fire, so that the flames jump or engulf, rather than the fire itself* - WOW!!! I never thought of that!

Comment: @Lauren - Thank you for these explanations. Very clear.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to say/imply.

"Engulfed" implies the fire completely surrounded him.

"Jumped on" is an odd one, because it implies that it only affected a particular part of his body. It doesn't sound severe, either.

"Covered" is similar to engulfed, but isn't as strong.

"Devoured" also has a similar connotation to engulfed, but is probably stronger, and it also implies that he was "eaten" by the flames (which raises questions as to how he is still able to shout for help).

Therefore, I'd use "engulfed".

Answer (score 2):

Flames are commonly said to *leap out* in this context. You don't need a word to specify exactly how the flames actually *interacted* with the person because your narrative continues with him saying (in no uncertain terms) that he has also been set ablaze.

Comment: Leapt. Absolutely.

Comment: Is what is "commonly said" a good standard by which to judge writing?

Comment: @David: Not necessarily. But in this case, I believe the OP isn't even a native speaker of English, and there's surely no doubt that *leap out* is far more common in his context than any of *engulfed/jumped on/covered/devoured*. I also think it's unlikely a native speaker would say/write *He opened the stove and the fire from the stove...* Firstly, it would invariably be ***flames***, and secondly, repeating ***the stove*** is bordering on "unnatural". OP's version doesn't reflect "creative use of language", so much as lack of familiarity with natural English.